# Lucene.net - need to find similar phrases in the index

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

sorry for my bad english, i can read better then write ;)

I implemented the lucene.net in an application where iam extracting cells from an excel sheet in text and write them in an index. After then i searched the index with phrases which contains about 250 letters and write the result in the application. This works now perfect in case the phrase is exactly the same like in the index. My question now: is there a chance to find results if there are some letters changed? I have to find quoates nevertheless if somebody only delete one word in the sentence.

I am using Apache-Lucene.Net-2.9.4 and some important information:

```java
//used analyzer and IndexWriter
analyzer = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.De.GermanAnalyzer();
writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

//Used Field Properties
doc.Add(new Field("id", txts.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
doc.Add(new Field("DateiName", DateiName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
doc.Add(new Field("postBody", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));

for (int y = 1; y < 51; y++)
{
    var queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, "postBody", analyzer);
    string temquery = "\"";
    temquery += sheet.Cells[y, 5].Value.ToString();
    temquery += "\"";
    var query = queryParser.Parse(temquery);
    TopDocs resultDocs = indexSearch.Search(query, indexReader.MaxDoc());
    var hits = resultDocs.ScoreDocs;
    if (resultDocs.TotalHits > 0 && resultDocs.MaxScore > 1)
    {
        foreach (var hit in hits)
        {
            found = true;
            var documentFromSearcher = indexSearch.Doc(hit.doc);
            combineString += "Zeile: " + documentFromSearcher.Get("id") +
                    "\t" + documentFromSearcher.Get("DateiName") + "\t Zeile: \t" +
                    y.ToString() + "\r\n";
            tbAusgabe.Text = combineString;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried several Analyzers, read a lot about Tokens and Field-Properties, but i didnt find a solution. Somebody here can help me?

Comment: A few samples text showing *what you index* , *what you search* and *what you want to find* would be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [fuzzy query](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_2_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html) or a proximity query.

For example, `"foo bar"~1` will match `bar foo` and `foobar~.5` will match `foobaz`.

Comment: note that "foo bar"~1 will create a regular PhraseQuery with a slop of 1, which will not match if a token is missing, see  http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html#setSlop(int)